# Сетка символов из списка списков в Python (задача списков из книги al sweigart)

Tags: python, list

Есть простая задача из книги "Автоматизация рутинных задач с помощью Python":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался реализовать решения так:

```
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(6):
    print(grid[0][i])             #сначала выбираем строку где хотим писать
    for b in range(0,9):
        # каждый раз в одной строке по 8 раз проходимся каждым значением
        print(grid[b][i], end="")
```

Некорректен ход выполнения итераций. Сначала печатается 1 символ из "i" строки и только потом идёт вывод всей "i" строки

Но я понимаю, что это некорректный код. В моём представлении надо
как-то результат вывода 2-ого цикла вставить в аргументы print 1-ого цикла, но мне не хватает опыта и представления как это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно-ли я понимаю структуру кода для решения задачи?
А если правильно, как вставить результат print из 2-ого цикла в аргументы print 1-ого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(9):
        print(grid[j][i], end="")
    print()
```

---

Вариант с одним циклом:

```
for i in zip(*grid):
    print(*i, sep = '')
```

- `sep` задаёт разделитель, который будет вставлен между выводимыми значениями.
- `zip` объединяет в кортежи элементы из последовательностей переданных в качестве аргументов